# what is use of this state config focused ios UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

[image]

When focused state title/image visible for UIButton

Comment: What is the question or issue?

Comment: @Lion what is use of this state config focused ios UIButton. and this is my question only not issue

Comment: @Lion I also want to know what is state config focused?

Comment: @Jack check my answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState) states,

> Focused state of a control. In focus-based navigation systems, a control enters this state when it receives the focus. A focused control changes its appearance to indicate that it has focus, and this appearance differs from the appearance of the control when it is highlighted or selected. Further interactions with the control can result in it also becoming highlighted or selected.

Comment: so its for  Apple TV remote

Comment: It is also used in CarPlay for cars using a knob to select a UIButton on the screen using the knob.

Comment: _ a control enters this state when it receives the focus_ what does this mean exactly? How is this different from selected/highlighted?

Comment: I see a button being created in the Focused state in crash logs for my iPhone/iPad app - still not sure under what conditions this is happening.  Any assistive devices cause this state?